# $\frac{14x^4+50x^3+567x-90}{2x^4+3x^2+1}$ Solve for x in the denominator

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am coming up with two solutions, one I try and substitute $x=x^2$ into the denominator, and two, I use a computer algebraic system provided by my class.  I was wondering how to do the substitution so that it equals the CAS.

Here is the substitutions

Denominator before substitution = $$2x^4+3x^2+1$$
This is the term (idea), I want to use to solve.  I am not sure if it is phrase correctly, $$x=x^2$$
Denominator after the substitution = $$2x^2+3x+1$$

I was wondering do I have to factor out the two? $$2(x^2+\frac32x+\frac12)$$
I have done this when dividing polynomials and using synthetic division. Pervious to learning the long division of polynomials, I could factor.  $$(2x+1)(x+1)$$

Since $x=x^2$ I know have to return the equation to its original form and solve.

$$x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac12}$$ and $$x=\pm\sqrt{-1}$$

Here is the CAS;  My work up above in this post is more complete than the work I show in the CAS. I felt like I was headed in the wrong direction and I am looking for some pointers on the substitution first.
[image]

Comment: We have $2x^4+3x^2+1=(2x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 1)$, just as you have explained, by setting $y=x^2$ and using $2y^2+3y+1=(2y+1)(y+1)$. But what is your question there? Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: The answer given by the CAS (the exact not the numerical) is the same as yours. The way the CAS displays it is more proper since, for example, $\sqrt{-1}$ is ambiguous.

Comment: What problem are you encountering, exactly? Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: And of course $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$ and so on.

Comment: I agree with @DietrichBurde and Goku.  Your solution for the roots of the denominator are correct.  I do not see any errors in your logic or arithmetic.

Comment: I didn't think the $\pm\frac12\sqrt2i=\pm\sqrt{\frac12}$